# Does an index on multiple fields in SQL Server serve the queries for the first field equally well?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have this index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SomeName] ON [dbo].[Site]
(
    [CompanyId] ASC,
    [SiteName] ASC,
    [SiteCode] ASC
)
```

Now if I do a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Site
WHERE CompanyId = 'MyCompany'
```

Is the index covering this well enough, or would it be beneficial to create a separate index just on CompanyId field? I assume it is surely more efficient to use a specialised index, the question is if it is negligible or substantial difference.

Comment: Any gain in efficiency will be extremely small. The only benefit is smaller index rows so more rows on a page - so maybe the seek has to traverse 1 or 2 less pages due to depth and then if the seek returns many rows read fewer pages at leaf level matching the `CompanyId`. In the vast majority of workloads the first index will work well enough for both that it isn't worth paying the extra cost for maintaining two indexes on write operations. As you have `SELECT *` both will require lookups to get the missing columns unless the table only has the columns covered in that index

Comment: That sounds reasonable, thanks for the answer :) If you bother writing it in an answer, I can accept it

Comment: Its definitely a dupe. I was just too lazy to try and find one!

Comment: One small question though: if we have 3 fields, the index would have to be traversed through 3 nodes, and not just one to get the primary key which somewhat slower (negligible though), or am I misunderstanding how indexing works?

Comment: Yes you are misunderstanding how indexing works. The index key comprises all three values. And the index rows at all levels of the index will just be rows with the value for all three columns. So the upper levels have a row for each page in the level below with the complete key value (all three key columns) - relating to the min key value held on that page

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies it :) I suppose that means that complete key value means they have the reference to the primary key right away

Comment: You can use `DBCC PAGE`/`DBCC IND` to see the above BTW and see what the index rows at the upper levels contain

Comment: great, let me check :)

Comment: You probably want a *clustered* index to cover your (bad practice) `SELECT *`

Comment: I do not use SELECT *, it is just to make an example easier in here, but I do query all the fields from that table

Comment: Querying all fields is the same problem as `SELECT *`: you are doing a key lookup to get all those columns. And query performance questions don't really do *examples* we need the actual query and tables.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik, if your actual query specifies only CompanyId, SiteName, SiteCode columns (and clustered index keys) in the `SELECT` list, the non-clustered index will cover the query without needing to read the data row.

Comment: But either way the proposed single column index isn't going to cover any additional columns than the existing three column index so there is no benefit there

Comment: I do query data that is not available in the index, so it should be read from a clustered primary key index I suppose (I have that one as well).

@Charlieface It did not seem relevant for the question at hand, and it seems to be correct that it is not relevant as Martin Smith answered it. The problem with too big examples is that people would not bother reading, so there is some balance between simplification and the real query

Comment: It is very relevant: if you are doing key lookups to get the rest of the data then *that* is the most significant impact on any query on those columns, and adding `INCLUDE` columns or changing the clustered index is going to help the most. All you needed was to more tightly define what columns are in the table, what columns are in the clustered and non-clustered index, and what exactly you are querying. You can cut some of the columns out, but we need to see, for a given example table, what exactly is going on.

Comment: I disagree - it is relevant to a question you didn't ask but it is not relevant to the question you did ask. You didn't ask us about how good your existing three column index was. You only asked us if creating an additional one column would be better

Comment: This is why I did not include that information in the first place :)